# Does ArrayList use the hashCode method of added objects when adding them

Tags: java, arraylist, hashcode

Does the following code use the `hashCode` method of my `Scooter` class:

```
void using_ArrayList(){
        List coll=new ArrayList();

        Scooter s1=new Scooter();
        s1.setNumber("HR26KC345352344");
        s1.setHorse_power(123.321);
        s1.setYear_of_made(1997);

        Scooter s2=new Scooter();
        s2.setNumber("HR26KC34535");
        s2.setHorse_power(123.321);
        s2.setYear_of_made(1997);

        Scooter s3=new Scooter();
        s3.setNumber("HR26KC345352344");
        s3.setHorse_power(123.321);
        s3.setYear_of_made(1997);

        coll.add(s1);
        coll.add(s2);
        coll.add(s3);

        Scooter s=new Scooter();
        s.setNumber("HR26KC345352344");
        System.out.println(coll.contains(s));
}
```

Scooter Class:

```
class Scooter{
    private String number;
    private double horse_power;
    private int year_of_made;
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public double getHorse_power() {
        return horse_power;
    }
    public void setHorse_power(double horse_power) {
        this.horse_power = horse_power;
    }
    public int getYear_of_made() {
        return year_of_made;
    }
    public void setYear_of_made(int year_of_made) {
        this.year_of_made = year_of_made;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if((o instanceof Scooter)&&((Scooter)o).getNumber()==this.getNumber()){
            System.out.println("EQUALS:TRUE"); //OK
            return true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("EQUALS:FALSE"); //OK
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        System.out.println("HASHCODE");// NOT able To reach here...
        return number.length();
    }

}
```

I am able to reach `equals()` method. But not able to reach `hashCode()` method. Does `hashCode()` method is NOT used by `ArrayList` collection? Please tell me, as I am new to Java-Collections.

Comment: You may look at the source code of `ArrayList` and get your own answer.

Comment: Note that usually a hash based collection will have the word hash in it's name. But like @LuiggiMendoza suggested you can be sure by having look at the source your self.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike, say, a HashMap, an ArrayList does not need to use the hashCode() method since the order of the elements in an ArrayList is determined by the order in which they were inserted, and not by hashing.

Comment: Erm ... this explanation is not logical.  And the obvious counter-example is `LinkedHashMap` where the order of the elements is determined by the insertion order AND YET `hashCode()` is used when you call `add` and `contains`.

Comment: LinkedHashMap actually has two ways to get to the data:  one is by a hash table, and the other is by a linked list.  Only the linked list is ordered by insertion order; the hash table still needs the hashes.

Answer (score 2):

> Does hashCode() method is NOT used by ArrayList collection?

I assume that you mean the `hashCode()` methods of the elements of the `ArrayList`.  The *only* case where the element `hashCode()` methods are called by the `ArrayList` object, is when computing the hash code of the `ArrayList` itself.

You can confirm this by looking at the source code, or reading the javadocs.  (The behaviour is specified in the `List` API and implemented in `AbstractList` ...)

---

So, it is expected that you do not see calls to `hashCode()` in your example, either from `List.add` or `List.contains`.  In particular, `contains` iterates the list elements calling `equals` on each one until a call returns `true`.  The `ArrayList` implementation does nothing clever to make `contains` go fast.

---

I would also like to point out that the *explanation* given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23452669/139985) is incorrect:

> "Unlike, say, a `HashMap`, an `ArrayList` does not need to use the `hashCode()` method **since the order of the elements in an `ArrayList` is determined by the order in which they were inserted, and not by hashing**."

This is incorrect in a couple of respects:

1. The order of an ArrayList is not determined by the order in which elements are added.  It is determined by the order *and position* of the additions (and other operations).
2. The reason for using `hashCode` in `HashMap` is NOT to determine an order.  (Indeed, the order of a `HashMap` is nonsensical ... to a first approximation.)  Hashing (via `hashCode`) is actually used to provide `O(1)` lookup by key.
3. `LinkedHashMap` is a counter-example to the stated reasoning. It preserves insertion order AND use `hashCode`.

In fact, the two issues (element order and use of hashing) are orthogonal.  The actual reasons that `hashCode()` isn't used for lookup in `ArrayList` are more pragmatic:

- The addition of a hash table-like data structure would increase the `ArrayList`'s memory overheads by a factor of at least 5 per element, and probably more.
- Implementing BOTH `O(1)` hash-based lookup based on elements values (for `contains`) AND `O(1)` lookup by element position (for `get`) in the same data structure is very complicated.

`ArrayList` is designed to be memory and time efficient for a subset of use-cases.  Hashing would be a hindrance in those use-cases.  But either way, it *doesn't* use it.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious from your code, it doesn't use the hashCode. This methods is used in hashes, not linear collections like ArrayList. And search there is performed in O(N)

Answer (score -3):

Hashcode is used in only those collections which needs to identify unique values.

so its used in Set kind of collections.

in arraylist duplicates are allowed and hence no concept of checking hashcode.

Comment: hi, hashmap if you look at its api properly, it clearly says keys should be unique and hashmap keys are again a set only..so its using hashcode...when you do map.keySet(), you are getting set not list..go through hashmap keys properly. its same as set.

Comment: if Treeset does noy use hashcode , what will happen if i add treemap.add(1) and treemap.add(1), will it allow duplicates and if not how its managing without equals and hashcode ?

Comment: Yes, `HashMaps` use unique keys, but that does not mean that `hashCode()` is used only for `Set`-related collections. An `IdentityHashMap` can accept "duplicate" keys (keys where `equals()` returns true), for example. `hashCode()` is intended as a tool to allow for proper functioning of `Hash-`related collections and does not imply a particular use.

Comment: `TreeMap` instances use `Comparators` or the `compareTo()` method of `Comparable` objects to place entries. It does not make use of `hashCode()` at all.

Comment: ha and read my first line that is what exactly i have said  "Hashcode is used in only those collections which needs to identify unique values".

Comment: Which still isn't true. Collections that need to have unique values do not have to use `hashCode()`.

Comment: And in any case, it can be argued that an `ArrayList` is simply a `Map<Integer, E>`, where the key is the index and `E` is the element. So even `ArrayLists` don't "allow duplicates" in that you can't have a single index pointing to multiple elements in the same way that you can't have a single key in a `HashMap` pointing to multiple values.